# PHP Function inside of ECHO statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using this function below in Wordpress:

```
function wpstudio_doctype() {
  $content = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
  $content .= '<html ' . language_attributes() . '>';
    echo apply_filters( 'wpstudio_doctype', $content );
}
```

Problem is that the function displays `$content` above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, instead of adding the string inside of the `HTML` tag.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`language_attributes()` does not return the attributes, it echos them.

```
// last line of language_attributes()
echo apply_filters( 'language_attributes', $output );
```

This means it will be displayed before your string is assembled. You need to capture this value using output buffering and then append it to your string.

```
// Not sure if the output buffering conflicts with anything else in WordPress
function wpstudio_doctype() {
  ob_start();
  language_attributes();
  $language_attributes = ob_get_clean();

  $content = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
  $content .= '<html ' . $language_attributes . '>';
    echo apply_filters( 'wpstudio_doctype', $content );
}
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer.  I understand, but an example would help - would you be willing?  Thanks either way and I will now be able to fix this.

Comment: Hi John, this already worked perfect - accepting answer here in a few minutes - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of output buffering, just use `get_language_attributes()` inside an ECHO statement. In this specific case:

```
function wpstudio_doctype() {
  $content = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
  $content .= '<html ' . get_language_attributes() . '>';
    echo apply_filters( 'wpstudio_doctype', $content );
}
```